# How to use str.replace by replacing from a specific character and on/forward

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

1. This is a extract from a table that i want to clean.

[image]

2. What i've tried to do:

`df_sb['SB'] = df_sb['SB'].str.replace('-R*', '', df_sb['SB'].shape[0])`

3. I expected this (Without -Rxx):

[image]

4. But i've got this (Only dash[-] and character "R" where replaced):

[image]

Could you please help me get the desired result from item 4?

Comment: Try to replace using regex. You can use this: `R\d+` as regex and replace with nothing

Comment: If the last part is always 4 characters long, you could simply use `df_sb['SB'] = df_sb['SB'].str[:-4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using `str.partition()`:

```
s = ['A330-22-3123-R-01','A330-22-3123-R-02']

for e in s:
    print(e.partition('-R')[0])
```

OUTPUT:

```
A330-22-3123                                                                                                                                                                 
A330-22-3123
```

EDIT:

Not tested, but in your case:

```
df_sb['SB'] = df_sb['SB'].str.partition('-R')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.replace` works here, you just need to use a regular expression. So your original answer was very close!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"EO": ["A33X-22EO-06690"] * 2, "SB": ["A330-22-3123-R01", "A330-22-3123-R02"]})

print(df)
                EO                SB
0  A33X-22EO-06690  A330-22-3123-R01
1  A33X-22EO-06690  A330-22-3123-R02
```

```
df["new_SB"] = df["SB"].str.replace(r"-R\d+$", "")

print(df)
                EO                SB        new_SB
0  A33X-22EO-06690  A330-22-3123-R01  A330-22-3123
1  A33X-22EO-06690  A330-22-3123-R02  A330-22-3123
```

What the regular expression means:
`r"-R\d+$"` means find anywhere in the string we see that characters "-R" followed by 1 or more digits (\d+). Then we constrain this to ONLY work if that pattern occurs at the very end of the string. This way we don't accidentally replace an occurrence of -R(digits) that happens to be in the middle of the SB string (e.g. we don't remove "-R101" in the middle of: "A330-22-R101-R20". We would only remove "-R20"). If you would actually like to remove both "-R101" and "-R20", remove the "$" from the regular expression.